# Simulation in R to create a data frame with some distributions and missing values

Tags: r, dataframe, simulation, missing-data

I would like to simulate a matrix/data frame with (600 row and 3000 column) and the below information.

1. rownames: id1,... id600 and colnames: g1, ..., g3000
2. each column be a normal distribution (mean range = (0.11, 1.08) and sd range = (0.01,0.2)) and some with a right skewed distribution (not heavy).
3. some missing values around 30-40% as an example.

I have tried below as an example, but do not know how to continue:

```
data = matrix(nrow = 600, ncol = 3000)
p1 = rnorm(3000, mean = 1.03, sd =015) # where p1 is one of the columns.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @
dcarlson
please see the update.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to create the distributions and add missing values. Your description of a right skewed distribution is not specific enough to make a recommendation. First create the data:

```
means <- runif(3000, .11, 1.08)
sds <- runif(3000, .01, .2)
data <- mapply(rnorm, n=600, mean=means, sd=sds)
dim(data)
# [1]  600 3000
rows <- paste0("id", 1:600)
cols <- paste0("g", 1:3000)
rownames(data) <- rows
colnames(data) <- cols
data[1:5, 1:5]
#            g1        g2        g3        g4        g5
# id1 0.8753292 1.0745325 0.4684015 0.2328574 0.5842330
# id2 0.8968101 0.9084336 0.3457179 0.2920512 0.5531856
# id3 0.9325890 0.7536202 0.4380173 0.3227730 0.5394033
# id4 1.0798398 0.9249825 0.4303059 0.2132750 0.4712201
# id5 0.7472148 0.9565644 0.3778758 0.2706638 0.3598996
```

To create missing values we can randomly select a row/col and make that value missing. To get coordinates for 100 missing values:

```
miss <- cbind(sample.int(600, 100, replace=TRUE), sample.int(3000, 100, replace=TRUE))
data[miss] <- NA
which(is.na(data), arr.ind=TRUE)
```

A simple way to skew a column would be to square it, but that will change the mean and the standard deviation.

Comment: @ dcarlson thanks. How can I increase more missings in each row?

Comment: I've modified the answer to create 100 missing values and added the possibility that multiple missing values are possible in any row or column. You can always choose your own row/column indices and force them to be missing by creating your own `miss` matrix instead of letting R choose them randomly.